# How many ways can we deal a 13-card hand with at least one suit that does not appear?

Tags: probability, combinations

In dealing a $13$-hand card that with at least $1$ suit that does not appear, I came up with this:

We can choose $3$ of the $4$ suits, as in $3 \choose 4$, and then $13$ cards out of the $39$ cards (from the $3$ suits), which is $39 \choose 13$. Multiply them together to get $3 \choose 4$$39 \choose 13$, and there we have an answer.

However, I don't think that is correct. I think that I am thinking too simple and missing a few calculations and steps. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah the problem is you've over-counted.  For example consider the hand that is all hearts.  You get that same hand by eliminating diamonds and by eliminating all spades and by eliminating all clubs, the way you've done it.  So you've counted it at least three times.  Do you see the problem?

Comment: Also, you mean $4\choose3$ not $3\choose4$

Comment: Yes, this is a job for inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the set of hands with no cards in suit $i$.

Then you are seeking $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|$, which requires inclusion-exclusion. By symmetry, you get:

$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4| = \binom{4}{1}|A_1|-\binom{4}{2}|A_1\cap A_2| + \binom{4}{3}|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3| - \binom{4}4|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|$$

You've only got the $\binom{4}{1}|A_1|$ term.

Your answer is pretty darn close, however, because the number of hands that have voids in multiple suits is low.